# Call each button containing certain macro

Tags: vba, excel, button

I am trying to do a for each loop that checks each button in the active worksheet to see if the button contains a certain macro or not. If the correct macro is assigned to the button, then I want the button to call the sub and then go to the next button.

This is how I picture it:

```
Sub ExecuteAllButtonsContainingX()

Dim Btn As Button   
Dim Btn_count As Integer

Btn_count = 1

For Each Btn In Application.Workbooks.ActiveSheet.Buttons
    Btn(Btn_count).Select  

    If ***[The selected button contains Macro X]*** Then
        ***[Call the macro that is assigned to the selected button as if the button was clicked on]***
    Else
    End If    

    Btn_count = Btn_count + 1

Next Btn

End Sub
```

What I don't get is
i) how to check if the button has a certain macro assigned to it, and
ii) call the macro from the selected button

Comment: Does the macro depend on which button clicked it -i.e. does it use `Application.Caller`? If so, I don't think you can. If not, you have two good answers already. :)

Comment: Yes it does depend on which button clicked it and it uses application.caller :(

Comment: I think you'll have to rewrite the called macro (if you can) so that it takes an optional Variant argument to which you can pass a button. It can then test if this is missing (when called directly from a button) or accept a button instead of using `Application.Caller`.

Comment: When I think about it, this would be the key in combination with the answer from ChrisUnbroker. How do I make an optional Variant argument to pass a button?

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need your macro to know which button called it, you'll need to recode the macro which is called by the buttons to take an optional argument. The buttons don't need to pass anything when calling the macro, so they won't change, but this looping code will need to pass the button when it calls the macro.

For example, here's a sample macro that the buttons call, coded to take an optional argument:

```
Sub foomsg(Optional vButton As Variant)
    Dim btn                   As Button
    If IsMissing(vButton) Then
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    Else
        Set btn = vButton
    End If
    MsgBox btn.Name
End Sub
```

and then here's a macro to loop and call that macro for each button that uses it:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim btn                   As Button
    Dim sMacroName            As String
    Dim cf                    As ControlFormat

    sMacroName = "foomsg"
    For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons
        If Right$(btn.OnAction, Len(sMacroName)) = sMacroName Then
            Run btn.OnAction, btn
        End If
    Next btn
End Sub
```

Hopefully that makes sense. If not, just ask!

Comment: This is amazing, it solved everything! Big thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do that (comments in code):

```
Sub ExecuteAllButtonsContainingX()
    Dim Btn As Button
    'Counter is redundant if you use [For Each] loop.
    'Dim Btn_count As Integer
    '-------------------------------------------------

    'Btn_count = 1


    For Each Btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons

        'Btn(Btn_count).Select      '<--- This is redundant. You don't have to
                                    '     select button to check its properties.


        'If property [OnAction] of the current button is not empty
        'it means there is some macro assigned to this button.
        If Len(Btn.OnAction) Then

            'This action is called only if there is some macro
            'assigned to the current button.
            Call Application.Run(Btn.OnAction)

        End If

        'Btn_count = Btn_count + 1

    Next Btn

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the code you suggest will call ALL macros from ALL buttons. I only want the buttons that contains a certain macro name to be called. 

E.g. imagine that there are three types of buttons with three different types of macros, let's call them Button 1, 2, and 3. There are several buttons of each type in the worksheet. I want all buttons of one type to be called. E.g. the code runs through all buttons and execute it if it is Button type 2 but not Button type 1 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick - not sure what will happen if there's no macro attached to the button though.

```
Sub ExecuteAllButtonsContainingX()

    Dim Btn As Shape

    For Each Btn In Sheet1.Shapes
        If Btn.FormControlType = xlButtonControl Then
            Run Btn.OnAction
        End If
    Next Btn

End Sub
```

Comment: Use @mielk - his looks at buttons rather than shapes, and checks if a macro is attached. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your macro name is fixed this will do:

```
Sub ExecuteAllButtonsContainingX()
Dim Btn As Button

For Each Btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons

    If Btn.OnAction = "insertMacroNameHere" Then

        Run Btn.OnAction

    End If

Next Btn

End Sub
```

If it changes often you could pass it as a Parameter:

```
Sub ExecuteAllButtonsContainingX(macroName As String)
Dim Btn As Button

For Each Btn In ActiveSheet.Buttons

    If Btn.OnAction = macroName Then

        Run Btn.OnAction

    End If

Next Btn

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks exactly right, just the way I want it. However, for some reason it never goes into the "Run Btn.OnAction", i.e. it skips all buttons even those containing the correct macro name

Comment: Try changing the macro name in the sub by prefixing the workbook name, e.g. "Workbook1.xlsx!macroname". If this is not fixing it look at the value of the OnAction property in the Debugger.

Comment: There is still one problem though. Although the macro is executed, it stops with error code 1004 since this macro depends on application.caller